# Oracle "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier" = Error in Bold SQL Commands on Oracle 10 G

Tags: oracle10g

```
create table Coordinator(
cor_id char(6) primary key,
cor_name varchar(10) not null,
contact_no char(12),
address varchar(50));

create table Student(
student_id char(6) primary key,
name varchar(10) not null,
department char(20),
grade char(6),
percentage smallint,
contact_no char(12),
address varchar(50));

create table Criteria(
crt_id char(6) primary key,
min_cutoff smallint);

create table Company(
cmp_id char(6) primary key,
crt_id char(6),
cmp_name varchar(25) not null,
grade char(6),
package int,
contact_no char(12),
address varchar(50),
foreign key (crt_id) references Criteria(crt_id));

**create table Coordinate_with(
cor_id char(6),
cmp_id char(6),
date char(10),
shift varchar(10),
primary key (cor_id,cmp_id),
foreign key (cor_id) references Coordinator(cor_id),
foreign key (cmp_id) references Company(cmp_id));**

create table Placed_in(
cmp_id char(6),
student_id char(6),
primary key (cmp_id,student_id),
foreign key (comp_id) references Company,
foreign key (student_id) references Student);

create table Criteria_Branch(
crt_id char(6),
branch_allowed varchar(20),
primary key (crt_id, branch_allowed),
foreign key (crt_id) references Criteria(crt_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift` is a reserved word. You need to name that column differently.

### You should never, ever store dates as `char` or `varchar` columns!

Additionally the name `date` is also not a very good choice. Apart from being a reserved word as well, it doesn't document what the column is about. A "start date", an "end date", a "join date", a "due date", ...

Using `char` datatype is almost always not going to do what you want due to its values being padded to the defined length. I'm pretty sure you want `varchar` (or `varchar2`) instead.

If your IDs (`cor_id`, ...) are really numbers, you should define those columns as `number` (or `integer`).

So the table in question should at least look like this:

```
create table Coordinate_with
(
  cor_id char(6),
  cmp_id char(6),
  start_date date,      -- or whatever name describes better what kind of date that is.
  shifted varchar(10),  -- the name is just a suggestion, use what best describes this column
  primary key (cor_id,cmp_id),
  foreign key (cor_id) references Coordinator(cor_id),
  foreign key (cmp_id) references Company(cmp_id)
);
```